# Understanding relation between Neural Networks and Hidden Markov Model

Tags: neural-network, speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models

I've red a few paper about speech recognition based on **neural networks**, the gaussian mixture model and the **hidden markov model**. On my research, I came across the paper "Context-Dependent Pre-Trained Deep Neural Networks for Large-Vocabulary Speech Recognition" from George E. Dahl, Dong Yu, et al.. I think I understand the most of the presented idea, however I still have trouble with some details. I really would appreciate, if someone could enlighten me.

As I understand it, the procedure consists of three elements:

1. **Input**
   The audio stream gets split up by frames of 10ms and processed by a MFCC, which outputs a feature vector.
2. **DNN** The neural network gets the feature vector as a input and processes the features, so that each frame(phone) is distinguishable or rather gives a represents of the phone in context.
3. **HMM**
   The HMM is a is a state model, in which each state represents a tri-phone. Each state has a number of probability for changing to all the other state. 
   Now the output layer of the DNN produces a feature vector, that tells the current state to which state it has to change next.

**What I don't get**: How are the features of the output layer(DNN) mapped to the probabilities of the state. And how is the HMM created in the first place? Where do I get all the Information about the probabilietes?

I don't need to understand every detail, the basic concept is sufficient for my purpose. I just need to assure, that my basic thinking about the process is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On my research, I came across the paper "Context-Dependent Pre-Trained Deep Neural Networks for Large-Vocabulary Speech Recognition" from George E. Dahl, Dong Yu, et al.. I think I understand the most of the presented idea, however I still have trouble with some details.

It is better to read a textbook, not a research paper.

> so that each frame(phone) is distinguishable or rather gives a represents of the phone in context.

This sentence does not have clear meaning which means you are not quite sure yourself. DNN takes a frame features and produces the probabilities for the states.

> HMM The HMM is a is a state model, in which each state represents a tri-phone.

Not necessary a triphone. Usually there are tied triphones which means several triphones correspond to certain state.

> Now the output layer of the DNN produces a feature vector

No, DNN produces state probabilities for the current frame, it does not produce feature vector.

> that tells the current state to which state it has to change next.

No, next state is selected by HMM Viterbi algorithm based on current state and DNN probabilities. DNN alone does not decide the next state.

> What I don't get: How are the features of the output layer(DNN) mapped to the probabilities of the state.

Output layer produces probabilities. It says that phone A at this frame is probable with probability 0.9 and phone B in this frame is probable with probability 0.1

> And how is the HMM created in the first place?

Unlike end-to-end systems which does not use HMM, HMM is usually trained with HMM/GMM system and Baum-Welch algorithm before DNN is initialized. So you first train GMM/HMM with Baum-Welch, then you train the DNN to improve GMM.

> Where do I get all the Information about the probabilietes?

It is hard to understand your last question.

Comment: thank you some much, the subject is much clearer now. Just one last question: So the output layer of nn contains a neuron(probability) for each phone of the language?

Comment: Sort of. It is usually probabilities of context-dependent triphones.